# Why is it that my class is showing as not being used and thus can't compile my program?

Tags: java

extremely new to java and in my class(in school no the program) we are to design a class that stores weight and a method that returns the shipping charges. I'm clearly very confused as to what I'm doing here. I have this code but can't even compile as it reads that my class isn't used. Any help would be great.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ShippingCharges {
    public float weight;

    public void myPublicMethod() {
        weight = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the weight in kg?: ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
    }

    public static double main(String[] args) {
        ShippingCharges charge = new ShippingCharges();
        charge.myPublicMethod();

        if (charge.weight >= 2) {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for 2kg or less for every 500 miles is $1.10");
            return 1.10;
        }
        if (charge.weight > 2 && charge.weight <= 6) {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for over 2kg up to 6kg " +
                    "for every 500 miles is $2.20");
            return 2.20;
        }
        if (charge.weight > 6 && charge.weight <= 10) {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for over 6kg up to 10kg " +
                    "for every 500 miles is $2.20");
            return 3.70;
        } else {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for anything over 10kg" +
                    "for every 500 miles is $4.80");
            return 4.80;
        }
    }
}
```

also sorry if this has been asked before. I can't seem to find it

Comment: `public static double main(String[] args)` Main method must return void. You should only print, there is no need for the `return ___`s

Comment: part of the requirements says that I must return the shipping charges

Comment: Then move this code to a new method called `calculateShipping` and call that method from main. Again, main must return void. Your requirements do not trump the laws of the language.

Comment: Then you need to create a separate method for the computation, the main method has a set signature.  You can't change it.

Comment: That can't be done in `main` create a new method that returns shipping charges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main does not return a double.  The double return should be on your method. The return type for main is void.

Try this:  I took the liberty of changing float to double.  You can change them back if you want.

```
public class ShippingCharges {
    public double weight;

    public static double myPublicMethod() {
        ShippingCharges charge = new ShippingCharges();
        double weight = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the weight in kg?: ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        if (charge.weight >= 2) {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for 2kg or less for every 500 miles is $1.10");
            return 1.10;
        }
        if (charge.weight > 2 && charge.weight <= 6) {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for over 2kg up to 6kg " +
                    "for every 500 miles is $2.20");
            return 2.20;
        }
        if (charge.weight > 6 && charge.weight <= 10) {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for over 6kg up to 10kg " +
                    "for every 500 miles is $2.20");
            return 3.70;
        } else {
            System.out.println("The shipping charge for anything over 10kg" +
                    "for every 500 miles is $4.80");
            return 4.80;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        myPublicMethod();

    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is technically correct but I presume the question setter did not intend for the return value to be unused.

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for. It definitely gets me going down the right path. Thank you very much. And yes for now I basically need the return value to just be there unused for now.

Comment: For some reason this made the if statements not work so I just made public double weight in the shipping Charges class = to the joptionpane entry and that made it work

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ShippingCharges {
private float weight;

public void myPublicMethod() {
    weight = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the weight in kg?: ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
}

private double computeShippingCharges() {
    if (weight >= 2) {
        System.out.println("The shipping charge for 2kg or less for every 500 miles is $1.10");
        return 1.10;
    }

    if (weight > 2 && weight <= 6) {
        System.out.println("The shipping charge for over 2kg up to 6kg for every 500 miles is $2.20");
        return 2.20;
    }
    if (weight > 6 && weight <= 10) {
        System.out.println("The shipping charge for over 6kg up to 10kg for every 500 miles is $2.20");
        return 3.70;
    } 

    System.out.println("The shipping charge for anything over 10kg for every 500 miles is $4.80");
    return 4.80;
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
    ShippingCharges charge = new ShippingCharges();
    charge.myPublicMethod();
    charge.computeShippingCharges();
}
```

}